# The import com.vaadin.flow.component.gridpro cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, import, vaadin, vaadin14

I made a project using vaadin 14.7.1 to create a GUI. Now I am working on a different machine with the same project and I am not able to import the Vaadin Pro Components.
The error:

> The import com.vaadin.flow.component.gridpro cannot be resolved

Im using the Eclipse IDE and arleady tried to update the maven project and deleting the .m2  folder, but nothing works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you checked that the libraries are actually there and on the path?

Comment: How are you defining the Vaadin dependencies in your project configuration (pom.xml if you're using Maven)?

Comment: Given that your dep resolving works and the project is otherwise fine, the most likely cause is using the `vaadin-core` artifact instead of `vaadin`.

Comment: Libraries should be ok all not pro components from vaadin work only the pro components import isnt working

Comment: That is exactly the case what @cfrick described. Please check your pom about the correct usage of the artefacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states, that the class can not be found and therefor the
artifact is missing.  Given, that the setup in general is fine (so no errors
loading the artifacts, no broken artifacts in the local/caching/... repository,
valid version, ...):

You are using the wrong artifact: `com.vaadin:vaadin-core` only contains the
*free* components.  If you want *all* (free and pro) components, use
`com.vaadin:vaadin`; or add the pro components you need a la cart.

Comment: I checked about the artifact and I am already using the right one: `com.vaadin:vaadin`

Comment: I think there might be another problem with my pom.xml I am not able to figure out

Comment: I'll keep this answer around, as it might help others with similar
problem.  Yet I don't use maven so this is general advice: rule out your
IDE and check, if this also fails on CLI.  Next let maven or your IDE
list you the dependency tree or the effective class-path; is the
artifact there?  If it's there locate in your your `.m2/repository` and
do a sanity check (`unzip -l` the jar, check the surrounding `.xml`
file, ...); if you have doubts about the files, delete them.  If they
come back broken, your (caching) upstream server (e.g. company
artifactory) has them broken.